# AWS Elasticache - use case for Data Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

Currently, AWS DynamoDB has a feature called Data Streaming, wherein if certain records are updated, its sends out a data stream to be consumed by usually a Lambda. Then the Lambda does whatever processing it needs to do. My question is, is there same kind of feature for Elasticache Redis?

I did my homework and tried looking up AWS whitepapers and documentations, and the only ones I've got was the Pub/Sub feature, which is mostly used for messaging (e.g. chat like features). It seems not right to use Pub/Sub for the use case I am describing.

If there is really no feature like this in Elasticache Redis, is there a workaround to be able to implement it?

Thanks, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Elasticache for Redis does not offer this kind of ability.
Elasticache for Redis is a managed service which provides similar API as the [OSS Redis](https://github.com/redis/redis/).
So, in order to provide an answer lets scan through the solutions Redis can offer:

1. keyspace notifications: Redis has a feature called [keyspace notification](https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/) which allows you to subscribe to a channel in order to receive notifications about changes in your keyspace. this will, however, require that you place a persistent consumer that will listen on the relevant channel/s so it is less "lambda" appropriate.
   Another aspect is that the Redis will only report each event once (usually after the operation was done) and will not report values in the content of the keyspace events, thus will not match the same case of DynamoDB data streaming.
2. Redis Streams. it is a long ask from the Redis OSS community to supply keyspace notifications via Redis streams. This is much more like the DynamoDB data streams, since it will enable you to periodically spawn consumer lambda which will drain the events accumulated in the msg streams. Again this also will not provide the same value as in DynamoDB data streams, as the keyspace event will only be reported once, and lack the old/new data.
3. Create your own events mechanism: Redis now support function libraries. This enables one to tailor function like API to encapsulate application logic and clients communicating with Redis. in this case you could migrate your clients to use a pre-written function which will perform the required operation (set, get, push, pop etc...) and will also place the relevant massage in a... Redis Stream!. So this will allow you to periodically spawn a lambda  which will consume your proprietary events.

Currently there are number of open issues in the Redis project that could help in similar cases, for example:

1. [Issue discuttion on implementing Stream based keyspace notifications](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/5766)
2. [new Redis triggers proposal](https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/11927)